# how to center a fabric.js canvas element in a bootstrap 3 modal

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, canvas, fabricjs, bootstrap-modal

Does anyone have an idea how to center the fabricjs

```
 <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

element in a bootstrap modal?

https://jsfiddle.net/vg4j1ze2/2/

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I got it. Just needed to add the following CSS

```
.canvas-container {
    margin:0 auto ;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vg4j1ze2/3/